# How do frameworks with their own session implementation deal with thirdparty?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, session, cakephp

I see quite some frameworks and CMS's that use their own session implementation instead of the native PHP session driver. All for their own reasons.

Examples of these are Wordpress, Laravel, CakePHP(somewhat).

What I am wondering is though, if they set a cookie manually and do session handling themselves how do they deal with thirdparty packages?

Thirdparty composer packages might interact with the default `$_SESSION` and might try and set session variables while `$_SESSION` is entirely not used.

Still with frameworks like Laravel from what I can remember it still interacts perfectly fine with thirdparty packages and they all get put into their own session implementation.

Would love to know from somebody who might have some experience with this.

**edit**

An example of a thirdparty package might be a php debugbar which can read from $_SESSION and insert it's own variable if needed. I know frameworks like Laravel have their own debugbar implementation for this that does not interact with the native `$_SESSION`.

I guess I want to know if it's viable to totally run your own `$_SESSION` implementation without having too much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be a perfect answer but here is at least what I found out from dealing with custom sessions implementations & the latest Laravel install.

In Laravel 5.6 `$_SESSION`global does not exist no session exists however when using the `Session::all()` it returns token of the session. This is logical.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   dump(Session::all());
   dd($_SESSION);
   return view('welcome');
});
```

Returns

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "G22ETumV1CQoolo2sAV0SA4wWmxFrZjTXTli7ico"
  "_previous" => array:1 [▼
    "url" => "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
  ]
  "_flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]
]
```

And the `dd`

```
ErrorException in web.php line 16:
Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

From my own testing my conclusion is if the composer package that interacts with Sessions does not implement a Laravel ServiceProvider it will not be able to do anything with session.

Hope this is helpful response.

Comment: It is helpful thanks. I am writing my own custom session handler implementation but it's kind of a hybrid with `session_set_save_handler()` preferably I would like to get rid of `$_SESSION` entirely. I think it might be viable to do so since a lot of big frameworks have no problem doing it and hardly any thirdparty packages interact with `$_SESSION. Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

Comment: Your welcome @Stephan-v might be useful to dive into [the source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/master/src/Illuminate/Session)

Comment: Keep in mind that Laravel uses file based sessions(by default) it doesn't even use any of the native PHP session handlers. (Symfony has Native session driver that does interact with the session)